# How to send both command line switches and paramstring with TShellExecuteInfo

Tags: delphi, delphi-6, shellexecuteex

I am using Delphi 6 (yes, I know, but I am old school).

I have a problem with `TShellExecuteInfo`. I want to run this command: `C:\delphi\bin\Convert.exe -b-i` plus a paramstring (folder and name of file).

If I put the `-b-i` after the `Executeinfo.lpfile` then `ShellExecuteEx()` can't find `Convert.exe`, and if I put it in `Paramstring` then `Convert.exe` can't find the file.

I have spend 3 days on this, so I hope you can help.

BTW, why would Delphi suddenly start to save my file as text?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `ShellExecuteEx()` for this at all. That function is meant for executing document files, not running applications. You should be using [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) instead.  Simply past the whole command to its `lpCommandLine` parameter, eg:

```
procedure ConvertFile(const FileName: string);
var
  Cmd: string;
  Si: TStartupInfo;
  Pi: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Cmd := 'C:\delphi\bin\Convert.exe -b -i ' + AnsiQuotedStr(FileName, '"'); 

  ZeroMemory(@Si, Sizeof(Si));
  Si.cb := Sizeof(Si);

  if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Cmd), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, Si, Pi) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    //...
  finally
    CloseHandle(Pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(Pi.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy Weel at least covert is running now but it don't convert anything

Comment: @user2844963 This answer solves the question as it was asked. As to why nothing actually happens, that's a separate issue that requires a separate question.

Comment: @user2844963 need more information. What is the actual filename that you are passing to it? What format is that file in before the conversion?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau The file I am sending it is a Delphi form (.dfm) that for some reason have been saved as text, so I can only open it as text and not manipulate thecomponent as you normally would

Comment: That can happen if you open the DFM itself, instead of opening the unit that the DFM belongs to.  Open the unit in the IDE, and then you should be able to open the Form Designer and modify the DFM as needed. If needed, you can right-click on the Form Designer and choose the format for the DFM to be saved as to file (Text vs Binary).